# How to use Node.js req.body send data into MongoDB aggregation $match pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate-functions

I try to use req.body of node.js POST route method send a pair of number into Aggregation $match, $gte, $lte pipeline but does not work. See my code :

```
  <form action="/transact/getState/" method="post">                       
  <h1> Query Transact # Range with Merchant Name Form </h1>                         
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">  
  <input class="box" type="number" name="tranNoF" id="tranNoF" value="0000000" required/><br> 
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">  
  <input class="box" type="number" name="tranNoT" id="tranNoT"  value="9999999" required/>                           
  <input type="submit" id="submitDetails"  name="submitDetails" value="Submit" /><br> </div> 
  </form>
   //-----------Get----open input form---------------
 router.get("/tran_no_range_agg/", (req, res) => {
 res.render("transacts/tran_search_state_agg.hbs");
 }),
 //--------------POST to aggregation -with req.body. method--------------------------------------------

router.post("/getState/", async (req, res) => {
const tranfr = req.body.tranNoF;
const tranto = req.body.tranNoT;
console.log(tranfr); // --I can see the number 5000200 I input
console.log(tranto); //---I can see the number 5000206 I input   

const result = await Transact.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      transact_number: { $gte: tranfr, $lte: tranto },
    },
  },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalA: { $sum: "$transact_amount" },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
     },
   },
 ])
  .then((response) => {
           res.json(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    res.json({
      message: "An error occured!",
     });
   });
});
//---------------------------------------------
```

if I hard code with $gte: 5000200, $lte: 5000206   it works. Otherwise localhost shows JSON [] keep formatting. Why the number is not in $match pipeline, I need you help. Thanks.

Comment: The request body has data as string types.

Comment: Maybe try `{$gte: parseInt(tranfr), $lte: parseInt(tranto)}`

Comment: Yes, added parseInt in and it works , thanks to Mr. Wernfried Domschiet